# JavaScript expression within Angularjs Jade template

Tags: angularjs, pug

Trying to only display some content if a property on my $scope object is before now:

```
div(ng-if="{item.end < new Date()}")
```

However, it's complaining:

`Syntax Error: Token '<' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 14 of the expression`

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the "{}" char.

in controller add

`$scope.date = new Date();`

```
div(ng-if="item.end < date")
```

Comment: Interesting, doing that gives me `Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is an unexpected token at column 19 of the expression`

Comment: add in controller:  $scope.date = new Date();